# Self made microphone burns Arduino

Tags: arduino-nano, resistor

I'm very new to electrical engineering and I'm trying to read microphone input with Arduino Nano. I've made a separate microphone module ([based on this example](https://engmousaalkaabi.blogspot.lt/2015/10/sound-level-detector-using-arduino-and.html)) and plugged it into Arduino like this:

[image: Connection]
Unfortunately it was the last time my Arduino was working. It's no longer displayed as a connection, and acts "randomly", so I think my microphone toasts controller for some reason. Here are some more pictures and a scheme of my mic module, could someone explain what am I doing wrong?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNKELL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**R1** - CR1/4W 10 (brown,black,black,gold)

**R2** - CR1/4W 2KO (red,black,red,gold)

*I have no education in electrical engineering, so I'm not sure about the correctness of this schema of units, just pasted what's written on the pack*

[image: Back]
[image: Front]

Answer (score 2):

Your schematic shows R1 as 10k ohms.
Your color codes and description lists it as 10 ohms. 10K would be Brown, Black, Orange.

http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/reference/chpt-2/resistor-color-codes/

So R1 is the wrong value by a factor of 1000, you may want to fix that ;-)

As for damage to the main board, depending on the microphone used that may have put an excessive strain on the 5V supply pin. Does the power LED still come on at the same brightness as before? If not then the power supply regulator is probably toast. If it does then I'm not sure what the problem is, you shouldn't have broken anything else.